# Делегаты и их экземпляры

Tags: c#, делегаты

всем привет, только начал учить делегаты. и пока понял следующее:

для того, чтобы создать делегат, мы сперва создаем класс-делегат(да,да я знаю, что это не совсем корректное название )

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();  // Создаем класс делегата. (1)
```

класс-делегат описывает сигнатуру метода который мы сообщаем (от слова делаем общим) с этим делегатом.

```
// Создаем статический метод, который планируем сообщить с делегатом.
    public static void Method()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Строку вывел метод сообщенный с делегатом.");
    }
```

затем, мы создаем экземпляр делегата, конструктор которого принимает нужный нам для сообщения метод:

```
MyDelegate myDelegate = new MyDelegate(MyClass.Method); // Создаем экземпляр делегата. (2)
```

так как я понял, если сигнатура еще одного метода

```
// Создаем статический метод, который планируем сообщить с делегатом.
    public static void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Строку вывел метод сообщенный с делегатом.");
    }
```

- совпадает с сигнатурой класса-делегата, то нам остается создать только еще один экземпляр делегата

```
MyDelegate myDelegate = new MyDelegate(MyClass.MyMethod); // Создаем экземпляр делегата. (2)
```

и просто в качестве параметра конструктора передать другой метод с такой же сигнатурой(кроме имени конечно)

А если  сигнатура метода, который мы хотим сообщить отличается от существующего уже в программе класса-делегата, то нам необходимо создать новый, который бы описывал другую сигнатуру нужного нам метода(тип возвращаемого и принимаемого значений) и затем соответственно экземпляр по этому классу-делегату.

Т.е как я понял если сигнатура двух-трех методов в программе одинакова(кроме имени), то мы можем просто "клипать" экземпляры делегатов, каждый из которых будет  сообщен со своим из этих нескольких методов. И если три метода с одинаковой сигнатурой, а четвертый - с отличной, то для этого придется создать уже новый класс-делегат.

Я правильно все понял?

Comment: Кстати можно короче писать `MyDelegate myDelegate = MyClass.Method;`

Comment: Да, пока все правильно, скорее всего дальше изучите более практичные способы их использования и присвоения.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала изучения правильно.

По поводу последнего вопроса: верно, но не во всех случаях: существует еще **Ковариантность и контравариантность делегатов**: это касаемо типов, определенных в сигнатуре метода.

Если кратко, то:

Ковариантность позволяет присвоить делегату метод, возвращаемым типом которого является класс, наследуемый от класса в возвращаемом типе делегата.

Контравариантность позволяет присвоить делегату метод, типом параметра которого служит класс, являющийся базовым для класса, указываемого в объявлении делегата.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name);
    }
}
class Client : Person
{
    public Client(string name) : base(name)
    {
    }
}

delegate Person PersonFactory(string name);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PersonFactory personDel;
    personDel = BuildClient; //<-- ковариантность: 
    // переменной делегата типа PersonFactory
    // присваивается метод, возвращаемый тип которого (Client)   
    // является производным от базового (Person), определенного при объявлении типа делегата. 
    //Возвращаемый тип метода: Client <- Person == ковариантность
    Person p = personDel("Tom");
    p.Display();
    Console.Read();
}
private static Client BuildClient(string name)
{
    return new Client(name);
}
delegate void ClientInfo(Client client);
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClientInfo clientInfo = GetPersonInfo; //<- контравариантность
  // идет уже по отношению к параметрам, заданным в типе делегата
    Client client = new Client("Alice");
    clientInfo(client);
    Console.Read();
}
private static void GetPersonInfo(Person p)
{
    p.Display();
}
```

На самом деле ко-контрвариантность является производной по отношению к таким понятиям, как: **объект типа** и **тип ссылки** на объект.
Пример:

```
Person ob = new Client() // здесь мог быть прописан вызов метода  
      //BuildClient, возвращающий объект типа Сlient
```

Контравариантность будет идентична примеру выше, за исключением того, что
`new Client()` будет передан, как параметр метода.

Т.е., если изучать эти понятия "в лоб" по учебнику, то будет гораздо труднее, понять их суть, чем изучить, что есть тип объекта, а что есть тип ссылки на объект (что намного крат важнее).

*Это весьма сложно для новичка (и довольно специфично на практике).*
И уже не так сложно, правда?))

Comment: стоило бы пример кода ко/контра вариантности добавить

Comment: Как я отметил, это сложно для новичка и специфично на практике, т.е. весьма редко применяется.Вот неплохой  [пример](http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.28.php)

Comment: С примером кода непосредственно в ответе, текст может казаться более понятным

Comment: + сделал, думаю, изложил максимально

Answer (score 1):

Можно не создавать `delegate` а использовать уже готовый `Action`

вместо:
`public delegate void MyDelegate();` // Создаем класс делегата

....

`MyDelegate myDelegate = MyClass.Method;` – Алексей Шиманский

написать: `Action myDelegate = MyClass.Method;`

Comment: не всегда делегат можно заменить с помощью `Action` или `Func`

Comment: Вы абсолютно не учитываете, что человек только учится и код приведен исключительно в демонстрационных версиях, а так же совершенно не читаете вопроса. Там ясно сказано и про использование **возвращаемого и принимаемого значений** и еще куча всего интересного.

Comment: @AlexKrass, да это ж копипаст комментария, причём вместе с именем и даже от "1 час назад" единица осталась.

Comment: @Qwertiy, помимо самого "ответа" (первые две строки), тут еще попытка цитирования комментария к вопросу от Алексей Шиманский(предпоследняя строка) и "ответ" на этот комментарий(последняя строка).

Comment: c @Alex Krass согласен, но просто хотел показать человеку, задающему вопрос, куда еще можно "копать"

Comment: а по поводу копи-паста: не тот случай, чтобы умничать ;) подумайте логически, хотел бы чего то скрыть, неужели скопировал бы вместе с именем? наоборот, хотел показать принадлежность кода автору :)

Comment: и еще по поводу бесполезности ответ: почитав другие, полезные ответы, я понял, что возможно мой ответ будет задающему самым полезным, потому как упоминалось выше, человек начинающий и "академические" ответы могут его попросту напугать ;) особенно про ковариантность и контравариантность делегатов

Comment: и да, еще @AlexKrass, вы конечно читать вопрос умеете, без спорно! но вот понять автора вопроса вам на мой взгляд не удалось. Человек спросил про "клипать" делегаты для нескольких методов. так зачем же их "клипать", если они уже есть готовые в системной реализации в виде Action?

Comment: @SeriousOrange, все просто, загляните в историю вопросов автора и все станет на места. Человек учится, только коснулся делегатов и должен понять как вообще эти делегаты работают и взаимодействуют. Всухую подсунув ему системную реализацию Action на шаблонах, Вы только подсуните ему свинью в процесс обучения. Хотите научить - тогда расскажите про делегаты нормально, расскажите про шаблоны, как сделать делегат на шаблоне и только потом упомяните о системной реализации Action.

Comment: Мне не нравится ни один из приведенных в этой ветке ответов, они все забегают далеко вперед и говорят о непонятных вещах для начинающего, ведя разговор глухого со слепым. Будь я новичком у меня было бы куча вопросов к каждому ответу: ковариантности, эвенты, шаблоны, какие-то стратегии - что все это такое? О чем все эти люди говорят? И т.д. и т.п. так что не волнуйтесь, я считаю не только Ваш ответ бесполезным))

Answer (score 1):

Всё правильно, только как-то усложнено, обычно делегаты так не используют.

Чаще всего они, в связке с лямбдами и выражениями, используются для реализации стратегий. Самый типичный пример - использование fluent-интерфейса linq.
Реже, но тоже бывает - для объявления ивентов.

Кстати, на начальном уровне, может, и не нужно знать, как именно работают выражения, но знать, что они существенно отличаются от делегатов, и обычно не выполняются напрямую, а парсятся и преобразовываются во что-то - очень полезно.

Да, а между ивентами и делегатами разница, напротив, не такая большая, как кажется на первый взгляд. Экземпляр делегата, например, тоже может хранить ссылки на несколько методов сразу.

Ну, и да, как уже сказали выше, не обязательно каждый раз юзать конструктор, C# умеет неявно преобразовывать метод/лямбду в делегат, в том числе и методы экземпляров, не только статические.